# LocalAuth from whatsapp-web.js doesn't work, or I don't know how to use it

Tags: node.js, authentication, sockets, whatsapp

When starting the Client with LocalAuth, it is supposed to save the session, and allow me to use it to start later when I restart the server, but it is not working.

I read the documentation many times, searched for projects in Github, but I didn't understand how to do it.

This is my code:

```
...

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const client = new Client({
authStrategy: new LocalAuth()
});

// Definir la ubicación del directorio público que contiene tu archivo CSS
const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(\__dirname, 'static');

app.get('/', (req, res) =\> {
res.sendFile('index.html', { root: \__dirname });
});

// Servir el archivo style.css desde el directorio público
app.get('/style.css', (req, res) =\> {
res.sendFile(path.join(publicDirectoryPath, 'style.css'));
});

client.on('message', msg =\> {
if (msg.body == '!ping') {
msg.reply('pong');
} else if (msg.body == 'good morning') {
msg.reply('selamat pagi');
}
});

client.initialize();

...    
    client.on('ready', () => {
        socket.emit('ready', 'Whatsapp está listo!');
        socket.emit('message', 'Whatsapp está listo!');
    });
    
    client.on('authenticated', (session) => {
        socket.emit('authenticated', 'Whatsapp está autenticado');
        socket.emit('message', 'Whatsapp está autenticado!');
        console.log('AUTHENTICATED', session);
    });

});

...
server.listen(8000, function() {
console.log('Aplicación ejecutada en \*: ' + 8000);
});
```

Comment: Hey! I had the same problem but I was able to solve it with this -> [link](https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/1295#issuecomment-1069047171)

Now, I have a question. How did you solve the multiple sessions problem? If you scan the QR code, you can immediately send a message with another emit?